# $dl$ element in [confusion in minus sign]

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Although this is a physics problem but I'm struggling to understand a mathematical concept here. The way I see the $\phi$ angle in the solution, I find the element

$$dl = R sin \phi d\phi \hat x -R cos \phi d \phi \hat y $$

Could you please explain why they get a positive sign there? The component in the y axis seems in the downward  direction which I assumed minus.

The question is about "A semicircular wire carries a steady current. We want to find magnetic field at point p. Biot-savart law has been applied there.The current is flowing in the bottom half of the hemisphere only " [image]

Comment: What is $\mathrm{d}l$?

Comment: I think, that's a small element of wire we need to evaluate for doing the integration.

Comment: Is it the Biot-Savart law?

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry I should have given more information.

Comment: Is this a _precalculus_ topic?

Comment: Why are we integraring from $0$ to $\pi$ only? Isn't it a full circle?

Comment: It is not a full circle, yes.

Answer (score 2):

We have that
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}r'}{\mathrm{d}\phi}=[-R\cos(\phi), -R\sin(\phi)]$$
But this vector points opposite to the flow of the current (i.e. $I$ is going counter-clockwise, and this vector is going clockwise), so we need to multiply it by $-1$, because the direction of $\mathrm{d}l$ is the same as the direction of the current (by definition).